# Mute microphone key is not mapped on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, asus

I own an Asus TUF Dash F15 FX516PM that can be dually booted with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11.

This computer has four keys at the top that have the following purposes (from left to right):

1. Volume down
2. Volume up
3. Mute microphone
4. Aura key

The problem I have is the "Mute microphone" key does nothing at all.

On the terminal, I have used `xev`  and I'm able to see the KeymapNotify for the "Volume up" and "Volume down" keys, and the KeyPress and KeyRelease event for the "Aura key". Strangely, nothing happens when I click the "Mute microphone" key.

All four keys work on Windows 11, so I think the issue is related to the mapping of the keys on Ubuntu, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Asus Linux FAQ https://asus-linux.org/faq/#mic-mute-doesn-t-work ?